# Pushing object into globally declared array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I never used global variables in Node.js so I have trouble understanding why this wont work. I am declaring global variable that is array, than I want to push some object into it and for sake of debugging I just want to stringify it.
I tried it like this:

```
var test = require('./api/test'); //my class
global.arrayOfObjects = []; //declaring array
global.arrayOfObjects.push = new test(123); //docs3._id is something I return from db
console.log(JSON.stringify(global.arrayOfObjects)); //I get []
```

Comment: Why did you redefine the `.push` property to be a new object?  Did you mean to call the `.push()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the object you want to push into the array as an argument:

`global.arrayOfObjects.push(new test(123));`

[Array.prototype.push() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example)

Answer (score 0):

You must do one of this three, you are mixin both:

```
var test = require('./api/test'); 
//global.arrayOfObjects = []; not need to declare the var here
global.arrayOfObjects = new test(123); from db
console.log(JSON.stringify(global.arrayOfObjects));
```

or

```
var test = require('./api/test'); 
global.arrayOfObjects = []; //needed to declare with this option
global.arrayOfObjects.push(1);
global.arrayOfObjects.push(2);
global.arrayOfObjects.push(3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(global.arrayOfObjects));
```

or

```
global.arrayOfObjects.push(new test(123)); // I think this is the best option
```

Comment: Why assign `global.arrayOfObjects = []` and then immediately assign the same variable something else?

Comment: @jfriend00 I really don't suggest it... but the OP wanted to... maybe I will update the answer with an observation too, thanks

Comment: @jfriend00 I think it is better now, don't you think?